# Get node by text from xml

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0

My XML document is given below. I want to get the element block using the element head like Table,Table1,Table2 like that.I can't do that. Please help me to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <Fld_ID></Fld_ID>
        <Fld_Name></Fld_Name>
        <Fld_Address></Fld_Address>
    </Table>
    <Table1>
        <Fld_Bank></Fld_Bank>
        <Fld_Account></Fld_Account>
        <Fld_Balance><</Fld_Balance>
    </Table1>
    <Table2>
        <Fld_Item1 name="xx" price="00" ></Fld_Item1>
        <Fld_Item2 name="xx" price="00" ></Fld_Item2>
    </Table2>
</NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path); // or .Parse(str)
var r = from e in doc.Element("NewDataSet") // root
                     .Elements() // first level child nodes
        // where e.Name.StartsWith("Table")
        select e;
```